# std::thread::detach hangs in VS2013

Tags: windows, multithreading, c++11

My DLL application creates a new class in an exported function when it gets called. The class constructor creates a new thread. After calling detach() the main thread does NOT continue and the entire application hangs.

In class constructor:

```
spawn().detach();
```

private member function:

```
std::thread spawn() {
    return std::thread([=] { WriteProcess(false); });
}
```

WriteProcess:

```
for (;; std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(LOG_THREAD_TICK_RATE)))
{
    // does stuff
}
```

Omitting lambdas for creating a thread does not solve it.

Using `CreateThread` this issue does not occur and `WriteProcess` works as expected.

I am using VS2013 C++11 on Windows 8 and I'm currently not able to debug the process where my dll gets loaded into.

Comment: Are you creating the thread from the constructor of a global object in the DLL, or perhaps from the DllMain function?  That might cause a deadlock, depending on how Microsoft have implemented std::thread.

Comment: Yes, it is a global ``std::unique_ptr``. And from my exported function (not DllMain) I create a new class instance using ``reset(new MyClass())``.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, provided the `unique_ptr` is initially empty.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple test project that loads your DLL, to see whether or not the same problem occurs?